# Updation frequently fails on MIUI 8.2.5

Tags: rom, ota-update, miui

I want to update my **Redmi 3S Prime** with miui 8.1.1 stable ROM to miui 8.2.5 (643 MB ;STABLE), I just downloaded the ROM via updater app in the mobile and when it completes the app shows that *please retry to download the file*. Since the the release of ROM in May 2017, i downloaded the required ROM about 10-12 times.Now help me solve this issue.

Comment: after download, please check folder named 'downloaded rom' in internal memory. If you can see miui zip there, your download was successful. And, after downloading, the updater app  process zip file, and tells you to reboot after complete.

Comment: No way ????????  It continues like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JUVF.png

Comment: 1. Check updater app  settings, like `download updates automatically, through WiFi ` etc  are set. 2. Go to settings->applications, clear cache of updater app( system app). then try again

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Xiaomi PC suit from this link: pcsuite.mi.com/
2. Go to fastboot mode (Turn Off phone turn on using power and volume down 
   button) and connect device to computer and turn on PC suit
   Here is process to install rom from PC suit
   en.miui.com/thread-95630-1-1.html
3. Select a Global option and click on the flash device.It will install China Stable Rom.
4. After that download Global Stable Rom from the following link 
   http://en.miui.com/download-303.html Flash it from updater app

**Note:** Please take the backup before doing any steps. It will wipe out your staorage

Comment:  I want to update without lossing data's. Is it caused by phone ???

Comment: I had the same issue with Redmi 2 prime It was not updating I tried several options. This thing only worked. You can also take backup using PC suit. It has a backup and restores option.